# Can more than one photon be in the same space as another photon?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, visible-light, waves, space

I have heard light described as a particle that travels in a wave. I have heard that waves are unique in that two waves can take up the same space as they are travelling, either through constructive interference or destructive(?) interference. So could two or more photons be virtually indistinguishable?

In a sense I am asking if there is a limit to how many photons could be crammed into a space.

Could a cubic meter of pure and heavily condensed light melt through planets like a hot knife through butter?

Comment: Light is not a particle but a quantum field. Photons are quanta of that field. While this may sound like a trivial shift in notation, it's actually a completely different concept. A photon, as a quantum, is a local state of the field, rather than something that "travels" like a particle would. The wave function of the quantum field is what "travels", but it does so in the sense of a smooth classical field. Its quanta, on the other hand, don't travel at all, they are merely the measurable outcomes of the field at spacetime points and, yes, one can measure multiple "at the same spacetime".

Comment: not in the oil-bouncing-droplet interpretation of quantum field theory

Comment: @Timaeus there is a repository of articles here: http://dotwave.org/

Comment: @Timaeus I just realized, I used QFT instead of QM as a joke. But if you think it, perhaps is not that difficult to generalize it.

Comment: @CuriousOne: yes, but you could say exactly the same for a fermion, that can't have the mentionned behavior, due to Pauli exclusion. So this answer is a useful complement to avoid confusion with macroscopic behaviors, but it's not the most directly related answer to the question, I think.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET: There is no difference between the quantum aspects of fermions and bosons, they are all just local outcomes of measurements on quantum fields. All they differ in is the symmetries they obey. Electrons are no more "real" in a classical sense than photons, which seamlessly explains 80 years of utterly useless confusion about "wave-particle duality". I find if fairly pointless to leave the OP in the dark about a (if not the) consistent interpretation of quantum behavior. Once the OP learns the proper concepts, his questions will be answered.

Comment: I agree (but for the order of telling things). The problem is that our answers are very probably very inadapted to his level of understanding, which is probably frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

This is not unique to light. For this behavior there are 2 kinds of "particles", the fermions and the bosons. The first have the "Pauli exclusion" phenomena: 2 identical fermions can't have the same state (quite close to saying "not be at the same place"), while 2 bosons can. This relates to their spin: fermions' spins are half-integers while bosons are integers (possibly zero).

Now as @CuriousOne pointed out the quantum mechanics world is very different to our macroscopic world an our intuitions are thus often invalid (a particle is not a wood ball :-), and the very notion of "being there" is not so well defined). For instance an electron is a fermion and have the Pauli exclusion principle. But a coupled pair of electrons has globally an integer spin and thus no longer have it as a whole (...but its component still have). Welcome to the strange world of quantum mechanics :-D

Comment: Cooper pairing, as I understand it. But there we get far to the question, and we get far to my safe skills. -> If I'm wrong, I'll delete this part.

Comment: Yes, but note I purposely didnot write "this causes.." ;-). BTW in the context of the question what interested me is not supraconductivity and what causing it, but finding illustration of bosonic pseudoparticle made of coupled fermion, and it's the only one I had in mind. :-) . If you like illustrations about how quantum world is alien to macroscopic intuitions, I guess this kind of situation is huge !

Comment: "as I understand it" meant "as I understood the Scientific American paper about Cooper pairing". I really won't pretend to understand high-temperature supra-conductivity (or even supra-conductivity, indeed).

Comment: well, just tell whether I should delete my footnote [1] above or not.

Comment: Indeed the French edition "Pour la Science" is selecting the best of it's own sources + other country editions so I think it's better. But this part of discussion is really chatting, as the mod is frowning ;-)

Comment: footnote deleted.